# SQL errors not propagated for batches

Tags: ruby, sql-server, windows

I am having a problem catching SQL Errors in Ruby DBI/ODBC on Windows working with SQL Server 2008R2.

My environment is:

- Windows server 2008R2
- ruby 1.9.3
- devkit 4.5.2
- gems:  dbi, ruby-odbc, dbd-odbc

If I run a single statement, then DBI will convert the SQL error into a Ruby exception.  That is, the following works:

```
begin        
  dbh.do( "raiserror( 'test exception 1', 16, 1 )" )
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
  puts "An error occurred"
  puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
end
```

Running this generates an exception as expected:

```
An error occurred
Error code:
Error message: 37000 (50000) [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]test exception 1
```

However, when I execute a batch of statements including raiserror, the error is ignored:

```
begin
  dbh.do( "insert into mw values(getdate());  raiserror( 'test exception 2', 16, 1 ); insert into mw values(getdate())" )
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
  puts "An error occurred"
  puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
end
```

When executed, the two inserts succeed, but the raiserror is quietly ignored.

Does anyone know how I can reliably detect SQL errors when using Ruby DBD/ODBC on Windows ?